# In Python, rearrange order of words in a dataframe when condition is met?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have this dataframe `df`:

```
        Addressee          Title   FirstName   LastName  SpTitle  SpFirstName  SpLastName
0  John Doe and Jane Doe    Mr.      John        Doe       Mrs.     Jane         Doe
1  Jane Doe and John Doe    Mrs.     Jane        Doe       Mr.      John         Doe
```

My data is over 50k rows, with unknown names. `Addressee` has different variations to consider.

```
     Addressee        Title   FirstName   LastName  SpTitle  SpFirstName  SpLastName
0  John and Jane       Mr.      John        Doe       Mrs.     Jane         Doe
1  Jane and John       Mrs.     Jane        Doe       Mr.      John         Doe
2  Mrs. Jane E. Doe    Mrs.     Jane        Doe       NaN       NaN         NaN
3  Jane Doe            Mrs.     Jane        Doe       NaN       NaN         NaN
4  John Michael Doe    Mr.      John        Doe       NaN       NaN         NaN
```

When `Addressee` has *Mrs.* first in `Addressee`, I want to swap *John* and *Jane* around, then mark the row as changed by adding a 1 at the end of the row.

```
        Addressee          Title   FirstName   LastName  SpTitle  SpFirstName  SpLastName Rearrange
0  John Doe and Jane Doe    Mr.      John        Doe       Mrs.     Jane         Doe
1  John Doe and Jane Doe    Mrs.     Jane        Doe       Mr.      John         Doe           1
2  Mrs. Jane E. Doe         Mrs.     Jane        Doe       NaN       NaN         NaN
3  Jane Doe                 Mrs.     Jane        Doe       NaN       NaN         NaN
4  John Michael Doe         Mr.      John        Doe       NaN       NaN         NaN
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

# Read csv
df= pd.read_csv(csv_file, encoding='latin-1')

# Add column to keep track of what was changed. 
df['Rearrange']= ''
df= df.replace(np.nan,'')
df.insert(0, 'ID', range(0, len(df)))

# Code I cannot figure out
####################### Pseudo code ##########################
#
# data_1 = If title == [(Mrs.|Ms.|Miss) & (FirstName comes first in Addressee)]:
#            df['Addressee'] == SpFirstName + SpLastName + 'and' + FirstName + LastName
#
####################### Pseudo code ##########################

# If the row is rearranged, keep track and add it to the list. 
    ids = df.index.tolist()
    for i in ids:
      df.at[i,'Rearrange']+=', 1'

    # Total rows changed
    changed = df[(df['Rearrange'] != '')]
    unchanged = df[(df['Rearrange'] == '')]
    changed['Rearrange'] = changed['Rearrange'].str[1:]
    changed = changed[(changed['Rearrange'] != '')]

    # Clean up
    del changed["ID"]
    del unchanged["ID"]

    # Print results 
    changed['Rearrange'].value_counts()
    print("There was a total of",data.shape[0], "rows.", "There were" ,data.shape[0] - changed.shape[0], " rows unchanged" ,changed.shape[0], "rows rearranged")
```

I have attempted to add something like the following, but it's not working quite right, and I cannot figure out how to do this, only if a condition is met:

`df['Rearrange '] = [' '.join(s.split()[::-1]) for s in df['Addressee']]`

How can I rearrange words to a specific order when a condition is met?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
mask = df["Title"].eq("Mrs.")

df.loc[mask, "Addressee"] = df[mask].apply(
    lambda x: f"{x['SpFirstName']} {x['SpLastName']} and {x['FirstName']} {x['LastName']}",
    axis=1,
)
df.loc[mask, "Rearrange"] = 1

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
               Addressee Title FirstName LastName SpTitle SpFirstName SpLastName  Rearrange
0  John Doe and Jane Doe   Mr.      John      Doe    Mrs.        Jane        Doe        NaN
1  John Doe and Jane Doe  Mrs.      Jane      Doe     Mr.        John        Doe        1.0
```

---

EDIT: Updated answer with new input:

```py
mask = df["Title"].eq("Mrs.") & df.notna().all(axis=1)

df.loc[mask, "Addressee"] = df[mask].apply(
    lambda x: f"{x['SpFirstName']} {x['SpLastName']} and {x['FirstName']} {x['LastName']}",
    axis=1,
)
df.loc[mask, "Rearrange"] = 1

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
               Addressee Title FirstName LastName SpTitle SpFirstName SpLastName  Rearrange
0          John and Jane   Mr.      John      Doe    Mrs.        Jane        Doe        NaN
1  John Doe and Jane Doe  Mrs.      Jane      Doe     Mr.        John        Doe        1.0
2       Mrs. Jane E. Doe  Mrs.      Jane      Doe     NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN
3               Jane Doe  Mrs.      Jane      Doe     NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN
4       John Michael Doe   Mr.      John      Doe     NaN         NaN        NaN        NaN
```

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my question to show variations of ```Addressee``` that are causing an unwanted output. There is data that shows ```  and Jane Doe ``` if a certain variation of ```Addressee``` is met. The would work well if everything in ```Addressee``` had the same format.

Comment: I attempted to adjust you answer with the following, but didn't seem to work. ```mask = (df["Title"].eq("Mrs.") & df["SpFirstName"].notnull())```

Comment: @feelsgood is `null` a string? Or `NaN`?

Comment: It's blank, so NaN. I have adjusted my question to clear that up.

Comment: @feelsgood Can you edit your question and put there expected output from the updated dataframe?

Comment: @feelsgood See my update.